# How to prove Projection operators are Hermitian/positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-computation, hermitian-matrices

I'm using Dirac notation here.

Given only that a projection operator is defined by the property $P=P^2$, prove that $P$ is a positive operator on the Hilbert Space, i.e. $ \langle v|P|v\rangle \geq 0 \quad  \forall\ |v\rangle \in H$.

I'm attempting to prove this using contradiction:

Let there be a vector $|v\rangle$ such that $\langle v| P |v \rangle < 0$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle v| P |v \rangle &= \langle v| PP |v\rangle \\
                        &= \langle P^\dagger |v\rangle, P|v\rangle\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

If I can prove that $P$ is Hermitian, then that would lead to the contradiction, but I'm not sure
how to get there.

Comment: Is $P$ supposed to be linear maybe? (You tagged ```linear algebra```)

Comment: If it is linear, any $x \in H$ can then be decomposed as $x = P y + z$, where $y \in \text{ran}(P)$ and $z \in \ker(P)$ (why?).

Comment: Given that $P$ is linear and    $P^2=P$, TFAE: (1) $P$ is self adjoint, (2) $P$ is positive, and (3) the kernel of $P$ is orthogonal to its range.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $L^{2}([0,1])$. Take any function $g$ in this space such that $\int_E g=1$ but $\int_0^{1} g<0$ where $E=(0,\frac  1 2)$. Let $Pf=(\int_E f)  g$. I will let you verify that $P^{2}=P$ but $ \langle Pf, f \rangle<0$ when $f$ is the constant function $1$.

Comment: Would it be different if restricted to the space $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the standard inner product?

Comment: @KnightShuffler I am pretty sure that you need [$P$ to be a linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)).